# DrawLine on ComboBox SelectedItemIndex

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress

just wondering if i can draw line on selection index for combobox .

ss: http://oi59.tinypic.com/lzdxj.jpg

```
referring to screenshot above:
number1 -|> i want to achieve
number2 -|> current output that i have for combobox using this code:
```

sample code:

```
void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e)
{
float[] location = new float[4];
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255), 2f);
            if (e.Item.ToString() == "2")
            {
                var q = e.Bounds;
                pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255), 2f);

                //Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
                var x = ComboBox1.Size.Width - 13;
                location[0] = 10;
                location[1] = (e.Bounds.Y / 2) + ((e.Bounds.Y + e.Bounds.Height) / 2) + .5f;
                location[2] = x;
                location[3] = (e.Bounds.Y / 2) + ((e.Bounds.Y + e.Bounds.Height) / 2) + .5f;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, location[0], location[1], location[2], location[3]);
                e.Handled = true;
            }

 if (e.State != DrawItemState.Selected) return;
            e.Cache.FillRectangle(Color.FromArgb(83, 83, 83), e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, location[0], location[1], location[2], location[3]);
            e.Handled = true;

}
```

how can i achieve it?

Note:

> Im using DevExpress ComboBoxEdit

Comment: Is your problem only to draw lines with different thickness or do you have other problems to acheive your goal also.

Comment: i got no prob regarding the item since i can draw lines for each item of combobox, but i have problem with drawing lines in selectionitem and also for my condition to how can recognize if that line was the one im selecting @wonko79

Comment: Do you want to draw a line inside the edit box? This cannot be done via the CustomDrawItem event. Probably, this can be accomplished via the Paint event of the control and only of the ComboBoxEdit.Properties.TextEditStyle is TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor.